# Hosted service not terminating after Environment.Exit

Tags: .net-core

I've got a .NET core 3.1 app with a hosted service that runs as a console application on Windows.

In case of an error I'm trying to terminate the worker with `Environment.Exit(1)`.

Now the problem is that, if `Enviroment.Exit()` is called before any `await` in `ExecuteAsync`, the application does not terminate. It logs `Waiting for the host to be disposed. Ensure all 'IHost' instances are wrapped in 'using' blocks.` and then hangs indefinitely.
When I await anything before the call to `Enviroment.Exit()` it also logs that, but it terminates as expected.

Here is the simplest code that I could come up with to reproduce the problem.
The `NotTerminatingWorker` hangs forever, the `TerminatingWorker` terminates. The only difference is a tiny `Task.Delay`:

```cs
  public class Program {
    public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
      using var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
      await host.RunAsync();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) {
      return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => { services.AddHostedService<NotTerminatingWorker>(); });
    }
  }


  public class NotTerminatingWorker : BackgroundService {
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
      Environment.Exit(1);
    }
  }

  public class TerminatingWorker : BackgroundService {
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
      await Task.Delay(1);
      Environment.Exit(1);
    }
  }
```

I would expect that both behave the same way, but that's obviously not the case.
Any explanation for this would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**:  The application should be able to run both as a console application and as a Windows service. The non-zero return code is required to get it restarted if it crashes.
And apparently Windows does not restart services that exited with code 0.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe the behavior you're seeing is a side-effect of how the .NET Core runtime does its startup: it calls `ExecuteAsync` for each background worker and then waits for it to complete. So a synchronous `ExecuteAsync` can cause problems. I've used `Task.Run` to work around this.

> In case of an error I'm trying to terminate the worker with Environment.Exit(1).

I recommend not using `Environment.Exit` at all. Instead, do a controlled shutdown by injecting `IHostApplicationLifetime` and calling `StopApplication`. This will trigger the `stoppingToken` for each of your background services, and if they ignore it, they will be forcibly terminated after a timeout.

Comment: I see. But how would I get a non-zero exit code with `StopApplication`? I need that to get it automatically restarted when it runs as a Windows service and crashes - Windows apparently doesn't attempt to restart services that exited with code 0. Sorry I forgot to mention that before, will update the question.

Comment: Using `Environment.ExitCode = 1;` before `hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();` appears to work.

Comment: Works fine when running as a console app, but not when running as a Windows service. 
In the latter case, the exit code is reported as 0 by `sc query` even though I set `Environment.ExitCode = 1` and the service does not restart.

Comment: @MichaelSandino: Are you using the `WindowsServiceLifetime` and not the [`ConsoleLifetime`, which sets `Environment.ExitCode` to `0`](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/10a59dd91a008fd6bcfc3fbf3978d77f8967b0e1/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/ConsoleLifetime.cs#L89)? `WindowsServiceLifetime` has [its own `ExitCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.windowsservices.windowsservicelifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#properties).

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks, I did not know about `IHostLifetime`. Tried it, and now `sc query` reports the correct `WIN32_EXIT_CODE`. 

However, the service is still not restarted! 
I'm just about ready to give up and settle for using `Enviroment.Exit(1)` with all its downsides.

Btw, I've accepted your answer now since it answered my original question.

Comment: It seems that Windows just doesn't restart services which terminate in a controlled fashion, whatever the exit code is. 

When the services exits gracefully with exit code 1, this shows up in the event log: `The TestService service terminated with the following error: 
Incorrect function.`

When I kill the process in Task manager, we get this entry: `The TestService service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 60000 milliseconds: Restart the service.`

Comment: @MichaelSandino: Odd. By coincidence, I am finishing up my first .NET Core Win32 service, and I will also need that restart functionality. So I'm about to run into that same issue. Let's keep in touch here (or on a followup question).

Comment: @StephenCleary Great, let's do that. I've pushed my example code here for completeness sake: https://github.com/msandberger/hosted-service-restart-problems-demo

Comment: @MichaelSandino: I did get service recovery working, but I had to use `Environment.Exit`. I ended up putting it in a type derived from `WindowsServiceLifetime`, overriding `OnStop`, and calling `Environment.Exit` if `Environment.ExitCode` was nonzero.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yeah, we also stuck with `Environment.Exit`, your solution is probably a bit more elegant. Will try that when I get a change. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @MichaelSandino: I believe you can get this working without `Environment.Exit` but only if you enable the failure flag, i.e., `sc failureflag "My Service" 1`

Comment: The combination of `Environment.ExitCode = 1;` and `hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();` does not seem to work for me for some reason. The application does perform a graceful exit, but it does not provoke a restart for some reason.

Comment: @Factotum: Did you set `failureflag`? See [this post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/06/servicebase-gotcha-recovery-actions.html).

Comment: I have read through that post countless times actually. Yes i did set the thing, and i observe no difference. My process has multiple background services. Whenever one of the services throws an exception i want to gracefully `.StopApplication();` the entire thing, and make it restart. It does stop gracefully but never gets restarted no matter what i try.

Comment: I feel that there could be more to it, something not exactly obvious. Like, does the type signature of the Main function matter perhaps (void, Task, int)?

Comment: @Factotum: Are you setting `ServiceBase.ExitCode` and not `Environment.ExitCode`?

Comment: I'm setting the `Environment.ExitCode`. i dont think that `ServiceBase.ExitCode` even exits in .net core 3

Comment: @Factotum: If you're using `WindowsServiceLifetime`, it would be on that type.

Comment: I'm not using `WindowServiceLifetime`  i use `hostApplicationLifetime`. I played around with it some more, does not seem like `Environment.ExitCode = 1;` and `hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();` work together at all. `Environment.Exit(...)` does work though, and triggers a restart like it should, but what if i want a graceful exit with a restart and not a crash?

Comment: @Factotum: If you're writing a Win32 service, then you should have a `ServiceBase` somewhere in your code. Set the `ExitCode` on that object.

Answer (score 0):

Handling the hostLifetime events in the Main method did for me the job. This is working for me on .NET6

```
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExitCode = 0;
        ILogger? logger = null;
        try
        {
            var builder = CreateHostBuilder(args)
                .Build();
            var hostLifetime = builder.Services.GetRequiredService<IHostApplicationLifetime>();
            logger = builder.Services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();

            // register on hostLifetime events for handling stopping and finalize
            using var hostLtAppStopping = hostLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() =>
            {
                // service is about to stop... do some cleanup stuff here
            });
            using var hostLtAppStopped = hostLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() =>
            {
                 logger?.LogDebug("Service graceful shout down, exit with code {exitCode}!", ExitCode);
                Environment.Exit(ExitCode); // ExitCode is set by the caller of hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication
            });

            // start the service
            logger?.LogDebug("builder.Run()"); 
            builder.Run();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger?.LogError(e, "Unhandled Exception occurred => exit with exit code 1!");
            ExitCode = 1;
            return ExitCode;
        }
        return ExitCode;  
    }
```

Comment: I had the same problems like descibed above. About code worked for me with .NET6.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).